# Как добавить в начало строки n символов на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Есть строка из произвольного количества символов, как можно добавить в её начало n символов с?

rjust не подходит.

Сейчас делаю, так, но думаю, есть что-то лучше.

```py
s = str().rjust(n, c) + s
```

Comment: Это учебное задание? Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос ваши попытки решить его.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не учебное, обычно когда добавляю пример, пишут, что всё и так нормально.

Comment: @Максим, чтобы получить строку  из n одинаковых символов, нужно символ умножить на количество. Никаких особых ухищрений, как у вас в вопросе, тут не нужно.

Comment: @insolor, я думал, для этого есть специальная функция.

Comment: А чем оператор умножения не устраивает?

Comment: @insolor, как-то сразу не догадался, что строки можно умножать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из предложенных ответов делаю вывод, чтобы добавить строке s в начало n символов c, достаточно следующего кода

```py
s = c * n + s
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c = 'u'  # символ
n = 4  # количество раз
was_str = 'данная строка'
new_str = c * n
print(new_str + was_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать новую строку через формат строки для питона 3.6+:

```
n = 5
prefix = 'hello'
string = 'John'
comb = f'{prefix * n}{string}'
```

Для более ранних версий питона можно сделать так:

```
comb = '{}{}'.format(prefix * n, string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно, ка то так:

```py
initial_str = "ABCDEF"
n = input()
res = int(n)*"c" + initial_str
```